# Spring security: manually bring back default configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring boot app that works correctly with OAuth2 (as a resource server). There is no custom `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method. Only

```
spring-boot-starter-security
spring-security-oauth2
spring-security-jwt
```

are added to pom.

I needed to add endpoints that should be unprotected. So I added custom config:

```
@Configuration
public class Security extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(GET, "/public/**").anonymous()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    }
}
```

Now `/public/**` endpoints are correctly open for everyone. But all other endpoints stopped working and in the debug level I see:

> p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication request failed: error="access_denied", error_description="Invalid token does not contain resource id (oauth2-resource)"

So I guess I somehow incorrectly overrode the default OAuth2 config. How to bring it back?

Comment: it's the only config that touches security. `@EnableResourceServer` is on main class. and all worked correctly before i added that `Security` class

Comment: i have cloudfoundry-uaa as authorization server. the problem occurs on server that acts only as resource server

Comment: You can start by removing the security class and see if the endpoints begin working again :)

Comment: @LukeBajada yes, without the security class all endpoints are working. but all are protected and i need /public/** to be accessible anonymously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer. following @dur comments, i needed to set resource id in the resource server configuration (as u can see below). i needed to set it to one of resources passed in token's `aud` field.

```
@Configuration
class Security extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("my-resource-name");
  }
}
```

but i have no idea why it works without any security configuration as spring's default id is `oauth2-resource`. seems like it's ignored when there is no config at all